# Given a .SQL file on an internal website, what options are there for pretty formatting on the fly?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, t-sql, prettify

So I want to put the files up on my local server, for reference purposes and aside from my regular DVCS because this will turn into training material later. But I want to be able to pretty format the SQL file. (Would be nice if it extended to C# code as well.)

I'm not sure what libraries do this already, and I'm willing to bet there's a Javascript library out there that does EXACTLY what I need.

> Needy whiny preferences `;)`: runs
>   with ASP.NET code, or in a jQuery fashion. eg: given
>   
>  `<div
>   class="tsql">SELECT * FROM ...</div>` — then maybe something like?
>   `$('.tsql').prettify();`

All I want to do is take the existing file, (maybe I'll insert it inline in a code block as indicated above) apply coloring to it, and display it in a browser window. I'm not concerned about reformatting the file for me, I'm not concerned about hotlinking or API references or any of the like.

I would google it but my googlefu is weak today, and I know there are at least five people on stackoverflow that know just what I need.

EDIT: If you feel you have a better answer, feel free to suggest it below, I'm sure others will want to see something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have C#, SQL, OracleSQL and an easy setup just as you described:
http://shjs.sourceforge.net/doc/documentation.html

Well at least google suggested it as first, hopyfully it won't go crazy with T-SQL :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. In the meantime, I'm going to leave the question open for a few more suggestions.